# Collection.partition in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I often write this helper to partition a collection, akin to the partition method in the standard library.

```
def partition[T](xs: RDD[T], predicate: (T) => Boolean): (RDD[T], RDD[T]) = {
  (xs.filter(predicate), xs.filter(!predicate(_)))
}
```

I was never able to find such a method in the Spark API. Does it exist?

Comment: No, there's no such method in the spark API.